# Can't install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS / grub failure

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation, grubrescue

trying to install 22.04 LTS onto my laptop (ThinkPad P50). I've had a working dual-boot W10+20.04 for a few years.

When I set that up, though, I made a bad decision and only gave 70GB of the drive to Ubuntu (also 30GB for swap, 1GB for boot/grub), so I didn't want to just upgrade, I needed to shrink the windows volume some more and repartition/reinstall. (Good thing is, before I started this I backed up all my files.)

I shrunk the windoze volume down as much as possible, which will give over 400GB available for linux stuff. Using the installer 'do something else' partition utility, I deleted all the old partitions, and started partitioning up the available space, like

/dev/sda5 EFI for boot: 500MB
/dev/sda6 ext4 for /: 400GB-ish
/dev/sda7 swap, 30GB-ish

Install seems to go ok until the end it says grub failed, 'this is a fatal error', and indeed trying to boot up it just says "unknown filesystem; grub rescue>". From there I can ls (it shows some labels, probably one per partition), and I can't guess any other commands (and 'help' is not one of them)

I checked my BIOS and I have secure boot off, UEFI/Legacy is Both, I've been googling, and I don't understand all this BIOS/UEFI/GPT/MBR stuff, I'm sure somebody more fluent in this stuff will be able to give me the missing piece of the puzzle and get me going again.

help?

Answer (score 0):

nvm, turned out whatever my problem was, boot-repair was able to handle it.

https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-use-grub-rescue

And for the record,

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4WgxgZ7hk2/